# Project Management for Website Agency - Change of Industries

Tags: software-development, planning, resource-planning, performance

I have a couple of years experience of project management in a particular industry. Covid-19 restrictions have hit it hard and I have been out of a job for the last 6 months. There is not going to be a lot of opportunities in that industry for the foreseeable future.

I have been offered a paid trial for a website agency as a Project Manager. They have given me a eCommerce website project as a test. They want to see how I do things etc. They have given me a Project Plan template and a copy of the PMBOK Guide (5th Ed) to complete and I have done most of it pretty well with some help from the book Complete Guide to Digital Project Management by Shailesh Kumar Shivakumar from the library.

But I am stuck on a few things that I can do in my industry, but not sure how things are handled in digital projects.

In the Human Resources Management Plan it says "Develop a performance plan for all staff involved in the project". Any tips, resources or examples on how this would be done with a digital agency for websites?

The Performance Management Plan - "Methods and techniques on managing the project staff so that outcomes are achieved" I am not sure what they mean. In my other projects I would use the standard tools of gantt charts,milestones, progress reports, daily meetings etc. Is that what they are asking for? Can I just repeat the relevant parts the Communication/Quality/Risk Management Plans? Or is there something particular to websites that I need to account for?

Procurement Management Plan - "Any selection criteria which will be implemented" For this project it is to select a CMS. Is there an industry standard for this?

Communication Management - for a project that will only run for approx. 8 weeks how often would you meet with the client and how often would you do progress reports? Is weekly enough?

They have standard documents for some of these things, but they want to see what I come up with. The project template they use is from a standard Project Management course from our country (not the USA). If I get the job and stay a year they will send me to this course so I will have a qualification.

I really need this job and this is a big chance for me.  Any free resources, example documents, books or assistance would be gratefully received. I have been looking for examples etc on the internet, I haven't found what I need for websites. I would love an example from start to finish for a website or eCommerce store that can give me some ideas to how things are done and what is important. I saw that someone in another question suggested the Digital Project Manager site, but I can't afford that right now. I have got several books out from the library which have a lot of theory but no practical real-world stuff or examples.

Comment: Why are you afraid to ask questions of whoever is managing you? If you're not sure how something applies, or what *they* think it means or should look like, why don't you simply ask them?

Comment: Hi, welcome to our community! As much as we want to help you with your situation, the way your situation is presented there's no specific problem being tackled and is prone to be tagged off-topic. One may read between the lines that the problem is "is there any specific methodology a project manager should follow on website creation industry?" and for that question, the answer is "no", as there's no unique solution. It seems you have several questions to get out of your chest, such as the one Todd mentioned above. Review your problems and narrow your questions so that we can help you further.

Answer (score 1):

"Methods and techniques on managing the project staff so that outcomes are achieved"

a) I´d suggest to apply Scrum, where in each sprint (2 weeks duration each one) let me detect, improveand and see the veloctity performance in the team.

b) Scrum allows constant communication, colaboration and trust between members, which is necessary to keep on deliverables with a lot of value.

"Communication Management"

-Once a week should be ok, but if you apply Agile, user might need to collaborate often in the project, because Scrum need global collaboration from each member involved in the project, even the stake holder.